# Netbeans C++ test file build error

Tags: c++, netbeans-7, googletest

I'm creating my first unit test (google test) in C++ using Netbeans. I have followed the official tutorial but I keep running into an error when hit the test button.

The error:

```
fatal error - error while loading shared libraries: 
/cygdrive/E/softwares_n_studies/Netbeans/installed/NetBeans_7.3.1/ide/bin/nativeexecution/Windows-x86/unbuffer.dll: 
cannot open shared object file: Exec format error
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of you project->run->Console Type and change to External Terminal.